# How to extend ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I need to create my own **ImageView**. 
This is my class:

```
public class Brick extends ImageView implements Serializable{

    public Brick(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Brick(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Brick(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

}
```

When I try to use my **ImageView** inside a xml **layout** file (as you can see below) I have a problem. I can see a black shape, but there is not the image (the drawable called d) inside it.

```
 <com.myapp.Brick
        android:id="@+id/myBrick"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/d"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

What's my error?

Comment: try android:src="@drawable/d".  app:srcCompat used with AppCompactImageView.

Comment: Banckground you have given as black
`android:background="#000000"`

Comment: @Dhaval Patel thank you :)

Comment: @Navas pk  actually you are allowed to use background and src togheter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `android:src="@drawable` in your **XML** Section .

```
<com.myapp.Brick
    android:id="@+id/myBrick"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/d"
    android:background="#000000" // showing Black Shape Background
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add_image /> // Add  android:src
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `app:srcCompat` or `android:src`  in your **XML** Section